# Communicating Asynchronous Data Retrieval status between UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uiviewcontroller

I'm doing some prefetching of data to reduce waiting time experience. In `viewDidLoad` of UIViewController A, I initiate an asynchronous function from a downloader class to call to the server to grab some small pieces of data. The downloader class stores this information in some Core Data tables. Then, when UIViewController B comes along, it uses that data to populate a table.

When I was running this on a simulator, it worked without exception. But as soon as I put it on a real phone and untethered the phone from the computer, the app crashed. When I got to VC B, I click on a button to open up that table. That button click would just hang, and the app would never recover. I checked the crash log and got the 0x8badf00d error. I'm doing my testing on an old iPhone 4, which could be part of my problem, but the app needs to run on all iPhone versions, not just newer ones.

OK, so I suspected why this was happening - the data wasn't back yet. As a quick and dirty way to test this, I put in a boolean user default that I set to NO from VC A. Then, when the downloader class got the data, it set that same variable to YES. In VC B in `viewDidLoad`, I put in a busy loop to make it wait until the value had been set to YES. When I ran the app, it instantly cleared the hanging problem, and the wait time in VC B was instant. The user would never know that this was present.

Despite this momentary success, I think that this approach of mine is terrible! Is there a better way than using user defaults? I don't know how to employ a delegate pattern here, and notifications might not work either. I realize that I am blocking the UI thread, but this is intentional. I can't let the user open that table before there is data available. Is there a more elegant approach that is more consistent with Objective C patterns?

I can post code if it will help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with notifications for something like this and do your downloading in the background (I couldn't tell if you were doing it in the background or not).

1. To run the download code in the background do something like

   [[DownloadManager instance] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doDownload) withObject:nil];
2. In the doDownload class post a notification when it is done

   ```
   //Downloading code    
   ...    
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DownloadsDidFinish" object:self];
   ```
3. In your VC B listen for the notification.

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(downloadDidFinish:) name:@"DownloadsDidFinish" object:nil];
4. In downloadDidFinish: you may want to do a performSelectorOnMainThread depending on if you care if you are on a background thread or not at this.  You can also post the notification on the main thread by doing the performSelectorOnMainThread at the time of posting the notification.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that this will work. First of all, when I say that the download is asynchronous, that pretty much means it is done in the background. If it weren't, my problems would go away because I would guarantee that my data would be back before the UI could proceed. But this blocks the UI in every case, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: As for the notification, what happens if the data is back before VC B loads (which is what I am hoping will happen and the reason that I am prefetching the data)? Then UI B will never hear the notification since was posted before B was instantiated. Do I leave it hanging for a notification that will never arrive (since it was already sent)? That makes my problem worse! I need some sort of shared 'state' variable that VC B can check before proceeding. Maybe user defaults isn't such a terrible solution.

Comment: If your doing your download in the background then something else must be blocking your UI.  You will need to code VC B to be able to be displayed when data is download AND before any data is downloaded and then load the data when the download finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can have ViewController B as a delegate with downloadedStarted and downloadedStopped methods. And you can start and stop spinning wheel animation in these methods:

```
[busyIndicator startAnimating];
```